# memoizing a function that takes a set as parameter

Tags: haskell, memoization

I am using `Data.MemoCombinators` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.3/docs/Data-MemoCombinators.html) to memoize a function that takes a set as its parameter and returns a set (this is a contrived example that does nothing but takes a long time to finish):

```
test s = case Set.toList s of
         []     -> Set.singleton 0
         [x]    -> Set.singleton 1
         (x:xs) -> test (Set.singleton x) `Set.union` test (Set.fromList xs)
```

Since `Data.MemoCombinators` does not implement a table for sets, I wanted to write my own:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.MemoCombinators (Memo)
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

set :: Ord a => Memo a -> ((Set a) -> r) -> (Set a) -> r
set m f = Memo.list m (f . Set.fromList) . Set.toList
```

and here is my `test` that was supposed to be memoized:

```
test s = set Memo.integral test' s
    where
      test' s = case Set.toList s of
                []     -> Set.singleton 0
                [x]    -> Set.singleton 1
                (x:xs) -> test (Set.singleton x) `Set.union` test (Set.fromList xs)
```

There is no documentation for `Data.MemoCombinators` that is clear to me, so basically I do not know exactly what I am doing.

My questions are:

1. what is the second parameter to the `Memo.list` function? Is it a memoizer for the elements of the list?
2. how to implement a table for a set directly, without using `Memo.list`? Here is would like to figure out how to implement memoization manually without using someone's library. For example, using a `Map`. I have seen examples that memoize integers using an infinite list but in case of a map I cannot figure out how to initialize the map and how to insert into it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. what is the second parameter to the Memo.list function? Is it a memoizer for the elements of the list?

The first parameter `m` is the memoizer for the elements of the list. The second parameter `f` is the function that you want to apply to the list (and that will be memoized too).

> 2. how to implement a table for a set directly, without using Memo.list? Here is would like to figure out how to implement
>      memoization manually without using someone's library. For example,
>      using a Map. I have seen examples that memoize integers using an
>      infinite list but in case of a map I cannot figure out how to
>      initialize the map and how to insert into it.

Using the same strategy of `Data.MemoCombinators`, you can do something similar to want they do for lists. This approach does not use an explicit data structure for that, but explores the way Haskell keep things in memory and lazy evaluation.

```
set :: Ord a => Memo a -> Memo (Set a)
set m f = table (f Set.empty) (m (\x -> set m (f . (x `Set.insert`))))
  where
  table nil cons set | Set.null set = nil
                     | otherwise    = uncurry cons (Set.deleteFindMin set)
```

You can also use memoization in Haskell using an explicit data structure (like a `Map`). I will use the Fibonacci example to demonstrate that, because it easier to benchmark, but it would be similar for other functions.

Let's start with the naive implementation:

```
fib0 :: Integer -> Integer
fib0 0 = 0
fib0 1 = 1
fib0 x = fib0 (x-1) + fib0 (x-2)
```

Then [`Data.MemoCombinators`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.3/docs/Data-MemoCombinators.html) proposes this implementation:

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

fib1 :: Integer -> Integer
fib1 = Memo.integral fib'
  where
  fib' 0 = 0
  fib' 1 = 1
  fib' x = fib1 (x-1) + fib1 (x-2)
```

And finally, my version using `Map`:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

fib2 :: Integer -> Integer
fib2 = fst . fib' (Map.fromList [(0, 0),(1, 1)])
  where
  fib' m0 x | x `Map.member` m0 = (Map.findWithDefault 0 x m0, m0)
            | otherwise         = let (v1, m1) = fib' m0 (x-1)
                                      (v2, m2) = fib' m1 (x-2)
                                      y = v1 + v2
                                  in (y, Map.insert x y m2)
```

Now, let's see how they perform:

```
fib0 40: 13.529371s
fib1 40: 0.000121s
fib2 40: 0.000048s
```

The `fib0` was already too slow. Let's do a proper test with the other two:

```
fib1 400000: 6.234243s
fib2 400000: 4.022798s

fib1 500000: 8.683649s
fib2 500000: 5.781104s
```

The `Map` solution seem actually to outperform the `Memo` solution for all tests I performed. But I think the greatest advantage of `Data.MemoCombinators` is actually having this great performance without having to write much more code than the naive solution.

---

**Updated:** I changed the conclusions, because I was not doing the benchmark properly. I was doing several calls in the same execution, and in the case of 500000, whatever was the second call (either `fib1` or `fib2`), that was taking too long.

Comment: Your `fib` example is fine, but note that the map created is not kept around between invocations of `fib2`. Also, you should try using `Data.IntMap`  to see if it performs any better than `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have for `test` is fine, although normally you would define `test` as a function on sets using Set operations. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
-- memoize a function on Set Int
foo = set M.integral foo'
  where foo' s | Set.null s = 0
        foo' s = let a = Set.findMin s
                     b = Set.findMax s
                     m = (a+b) `div` 2
                     (lo,found,hi) = Set.splitMember m s
                 in if a >= b
                      then 1
                      else (if found then 1 else 0) + foo lo + foo hi
```

This is a very inefficient way of counting the number of elements in a set, but note how `foo'` is defined in terms of Set operations.

Re your other questions:

> 1. what is the second parameter to the Memo.list function? Is it a memoizer for the elements of the list?

`Memo.list` has signature `Memo a -> Memo [a]`, so in the expression `Memo.list m f` we have:

```
m :: Memo a
f :: [a] -> r    -- some type r
Memo.list m f :: [a] -> r
```

So `f` is the function on `[a]` that you are memoizing, and `m` is a memoizer for functions taking a parameter of type `a`.

> 2. how to implement a table for a set directly?

It depends on what you mean by "directly". Memoizing in this fashion is going to involving creating an (possibly infinite) lazy data structure. The `string`, `integral` and `list` memoizers all use some form a lazy trie. This is very different from memoization in imperative languages where you explicitly check a hash map to see if you've already computed something and update that hash map with the function's value, etc. (Btw - you can do that sort of memoization in the ST or IO monads and it might work even better than the Data.Memocombinators approach - something to consider.)

Your idea of memoizing a `Set a -> r` function by passing to a list is a fine idea, but I would use to/from AscList:

```
set m f = Memo.list m (f . Set.fromAscList) . Set.toAscList
```

That way the set `Set.fromList [3,4,5]` will re-use the same part of the trie that was created to memoize the value for `Set.fromList [3,4]`.